# how to use strcmp in g++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I compiled .cc file whith g++ on linux ubuntu, I want to use srtcmp() function to compare two strings. the strings are not constant. user will give both of them,  but I get this error:

error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

and this is my code:

```
if (!strcmp(a[i].personalNo,pcode)){
    #some code
}
```

which function can I use instead of strcmp() to compare two strings?

Comment: One of the arguments you pass is not a string, but a single character. Notice that the error message says `char`, not `char*`. By the way, in C++ you should be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of old C-style strings and pointers.

Comment: What types are `personalNo` and `pcode`?

Comment: The code you've shown us is perfectly valid if `a[i].personalno` and `pcode` are of the correct type. Therefore the problem is in code you haven't shown us. Please read this: [mcve] and update your question to show us your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't on the function but on the way that you're using it.

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

`strcmp` takes two `const char *` arguments.

The error tells you that you are giving the function a `char` so the problem is on the types of `personalNo` and/or `pcode`. Your mistake is probably on the declaration of the type of those two variables. You would want to change their type to `char *` as `char` only stores one character while `char *` is an array of characters.

Also, an another way to compare two strings in C++ is to use `std::string`. Then you can just do the following (provided that both `personalNo` and `pcode` are `std::string`:

```
if (a[i].personalNo != pcode){
    #some code
}
```